# Comparar a mesma variavel no PHP

Tags: php, variáveis

Tenho a mesma variável onde ela pode assumir dois valores

```
<?php if($adm1){
      $email = 'fulano@email.com';
}elseif( $adm1){
      $email = 'ciclano@email.com';
}
```

Como comparar as duas variaveis da seguinte forma, se qualquer coisa que vier diferente desses dois emails eu devo emitir um alerta

Pensei da seguinte forma:

```
<?php if($email !='fulano@email.com' OR $email !='ciclano@email.com'){
        echo 'alerta aqui';
```

}

Mas mesmo que o email caia em uma dessas condições, sempre vai retornar errado;

O fato é que queria emitir um aviso sempre que o email for diferente dessas duas opções.

Comment: Não entendi qual sua dificuldade. Você não sabe qual é o operador usado para `OR`? Você quer um `AND`?

Comment: Desculpa to no inicio do PHP. O que estou precisando é comparar os valores onde o $email sempre assume um unico valor e o que preciso é validar se o valor que ele recebeu é diferente das duas opcoes que mencionei, caso seja emito um alerta.

Comment: Isto você já escreveu na pergunta.

Comment: A pergunta que não quer calar, `$email` precisa ser diferente de ambos os valores ou de apenas um deles?

Comment: Se apenas um dos valores vier diferente já deve emitir o alerta, acho que por isso que complicou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um modo que uso sempre que uma variável poder assumir varios valores é:

```
$possibilidades = array(
    'fulano@email.com',
    'ciclano@email.com',
);

if(in_array($email, $possibilidades)){
    // O valor assumir alguma das possibilidades
}

if(!in_array($email, $possibilidades)){
    // O valor não assumir nenhuma das possibilidades
}
```

O `in_array` pode ser usado como um `||` para várias possibilidades.
Também facilitando a inserção de novas possibilidades.

- No seu caso é só usar o segundo tipo, que tem `!in_array`.

Comment: Já tem resposta semelhante

Comment: Desculpe @Mastria aqui estava apenas 2, e 1 removida, sua edição foi a 8min minha resposta a 3min, posso ter demorado 5 para digitar, o que seria um "pensamento similar", não acha?

Comment: Dessa forma deu certo. Que isso, uma coisa simples complicou tanto a cabeça. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Então marque esta como correta, para acabar com a confusão...

Answer (score 3):

Teste assim, com o operador `&&` de comparação:

```
if ($email !='fulano@email.com' && $email !='ciclano@email.com') {
    echo 'alerta aqui';
}
```

Ou ainda, utilizando array, assim pode inserir quantos emails quiser:

```
if (!in_array($email, array('fulano@email.com', 'ciclano@email.com'))) {
    echo 'alerta aqui';
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ComparingVariableTwice.php).

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que é isto que deseja:

```
if ($email !='fulano@email.com' && $email !='ciclano@email.com') {
```

Isto diz que ambas devem ser diferentes.

ou

```
if (!($email == 'fulano@email.com' || $email == 'ciclano@email.com')) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Operator/Or.php).

Aqui diz que qualquer uma que seja igual a estes valores NÃO deve executar o bloco.

Não entendi qual é o objetivo, não entendi o que espera de fato.

Comment: O correto é utilizar o operador `&&` pois utilizando `||` mesmo o email sendo igual a uma dessas duas opções, cairá no if. Abraço

Comment: Ah, eu tenho que estudar lógica? Entendi. Eu não sei o que ele quer ainda. Pode ser que seja isto mesmo, mas sem ele esclarecer, complica.

Comment: Não foi pra você bigdown, o @Diego apagou o comentário dele dizendo que meu comentário estava incorreto, desculpe.

Comment: Não falei que estava incorreto, apenas achei que no fim das contas nem a pergunta está clara. Ou que as duas situações atenderiam ele. Tudo bem, não está mais aqui quem comentou.

Comment: @Mastria blz, só para constar, eu não negativei a sua, ainda não votei em nada aqui até ter ctz do q ele quer.

Comment: Está um pouco confuso sim, mas pelo que parece é exibir alerta se o email for diferente desses dois, algo básico. Também não entendi a negativação!

Comment: A que faz sentido é o `&&`, mas a frase dele tá ambígua.

Comment: Também não negativei.

Comment: Resolvi deixar só a que faz sentido.

Comment: Galera, ta tranquilo, todas as ajudas são bem vindas. Mas veja so se em um determinado momento a variavel $email assumir o valor 'ciclano@email.com' a condicao  $email !='fulano@email.com' vai ficar como true e logo vai emitir o alerta, mas dessa forma estaria errada, por que a variavel  $email teria a segunda opção de valor 'ciclano@email.com'.

Comment: É um negocio bobo creio eu, mas deu um nó na minha cabeça, é puramente questão de logica que não to entendendo

Comment: @lima99 A variável não pode ter dois valores, ou tem um ou tem o outro.